# How do I validate a group of textboxes using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have group of check-boxes and corresponding text-boxes with them.  I can get each checkbox one by one, but how do I get the group of textboxes so I can validate them?

Here is my javascript code below:

```
function validate_orderform(proform) 
{           
var flag=0;
for (var i = 0; i < proform.chk.length; i++) {
   if (proform.chk[i].checked && proform.quant[i].value=="") {       
        flag=1;
   }
}

if(flag==1){
return false;
}

return true;
}
```

and my html code:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk"></td>
<td><input type="text" size="10" id="quant1" name="quant1"></td>...and so on
```

Comment: What do you have to check? if field is empty? if it's a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If name of textboxes are different then you can access all textboxes by

```
 var txtObjList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 for(var i=0; i < txtObjList.length; i++){
    if(txtObjList[i].getAttribute("type") == "text" && this.value != ""){
      // success for i+1 textbox
   }
 }
```

Or you can give common class name to all textboxes and then can access by

```
 var txtObjList = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
 for(var i=0; i < txtObjList.length; i++){
    if(this.value != ""){
      // success for i+1 textbox
   }
 }
```

Remember by using javascript library such as jquery, prototype your work will be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of methods you could use, you could use document.getElementsByTagName to retrieve all of the input elements, check their type etc... It works but it's slow and potentially expensive depending on how complex your form is.

If you have a group of checkboxes and each one has it's own text box then you could group them, so add a common name to each type, e.g.

```
Entry 1:
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk"/>
<input type="text" id="quant1" name="quant"/>

Entry 2:
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk"/>
<input type="text" id="quant2" name="quant"/>
```

Then you can use the document.getElementsByName method, so in this instance the following would retrieve a collection of 2 objects for you're text boxes:

```
var myTextBoxes = document.getElementsByName("quant");
```

Comment: Also you could optimize your for-loop a bit more by changing it to "for (var i = 0, j = proform.chk.length; i < j; i++) { ... }".  That way you wont be evaluating the length of the collection each iteration.